# Is it against the regualtions to install a dummy set of landing gear during aircraft maintenance?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, airbus-a320, easa-regulations, landing-gear

We will be removing a set of landing gear for overhaul, so we are arranging a set of unserviceable landing gear to keep the aircraft mobile.

I would like to know if doing so is against any FAA or EASA regulations.

Comment: Mobile how? Are you talking about being able to roll it around, or actually taxi under power?

Comment: To roll it around

Comment: I can't see why there would be anything against regs, you aren't operating the aircraft.

Comment: Do you have rock solid safeguards in place to prevent the airplane from being signed off and re-entering service with the unserviceable gear?  If it's taken out of an airworthy condition for maintenance I can't see this being a problem, but you'd better be able to explain your mitigations to any auditor.

Comment: It almost seems to be too good a solution.  A couple of saw horses sitting on dollies may be more obvious to even the most casual observer.  Or perhaps removing the wing might be a hint.  But speaking to a local shop may yield a definitive answer.  Common sense would indicate, with loads of placards, the plane was out of service.  As a safety precaution, one could make the plane unflyable some other way, like removing the prop.